# Windows 7 check if bootloader is working without rebooting

Tags: windows-7, boot, bcd, bcdedit

My setup was win xp on main partition and win7 on the extended. Win7 was installed after win xp. The active partition is the win xp one, therefore the win7 bootmgr is located in D:\Boot. D being the win xp drive as seen from win 7. I decided to delete win xp by simply deleting all the files and merging the partitions later. Halfway through the process, I remembered that boot-loader is on the win xp partition. I quickly aborted and found some files remaining in the D:\Boot\ and in the root of drive D. Now I have ran the `bcdboot c:\windows` command, which seems to have restored the D:\Boot\ contents. The `bcdedit` output shows

```
Windows boot manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=D:
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-us
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {default}
resumeobject            {c4414ea0-48dc-11e5-946c-00241d8aa13b}
displayorder            {default}
                        {ntldr}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 3

Windows loader
-------------------
identifier              {default}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows 7
locale                  en-us
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \windows
resumeobject            {c4414ea0-48dc-11e5-946c-00241d8aa13b}
nx                      OptIn
detecthal               Yes

Previous version loader
------------------------
identifier              {ntldr}
device                  partition=D:
path                    \ntldr
description             Windows XP
```

So everything seems intact, however I wanted to make sure I can safely reboot. What else should I do or check to make sure the win 7 will boot fine? Can I somehow test the bootloader without rebooting?

**UPD:** The checks mentioned above and in the accepted answer were enough, system booted fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check that MBR and active partition boot records are of Windows 7 (NT6) format.

[Dual-boot Repair tool](http://www.boyans.net/dual-boot-repair-windows-10.html) can display format of MBR and boot records - use "Boot Sector Viewer" option.

Comment: Everything is in order here. And that's a useful tool in general, thanks.